# What are the characters on this image, and what do they translate to?

Tags: translation

Here is the image in question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be0iY.gif

Thank you for your time!

Comment: That picture hurts my brain. The characters are: `隔岸觀火`. Now that you have the characters, do some research (e.g., look them up in a dictionary), edit your question, and then people may be more interested in answering your question.

Comment: Hint: You might start looking at the [36 Stratagems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-Six_Stratagems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is 隔岸觀火(隔岸观火).

It means (比喻见有危难不加援助而采取看热闹的态度）watch a fire from the other side [from the opposite bank] of the river -- look on at sb.'s trouble with indifference; adopt a “wait-and-see” attitude; look on (without sympathy); Praise the sea, but keep on land.; show utter unconcern; watch the fire from the other side of the river -- not interested in sb.'s success or failure. (from http://www.iciba.com/%E9%9A%94%E5%B2%B8%E8%A7%82%E7%81%AB)